# Ayuda con Consulta sin mostrar todos los resultados

Tags: sql, select

Buen día, tengo una pequeña duda, espero puedan apoyarme.

Estoy haciendo una consulta en una DB, con el siguiente código:

```
select status as EstatusReporte, count (status) as TotalReportes 
  from Reportes 
  where CveAuxiliar = Numero 
  group by Status
```

En la cual tengo como Resultado:

```
EstatusReporte    TotalReportes
EN PROCESO           5
NEUTRO               3
RESUELTO             5
```

Quisiera realizar esa misma consulta pero sin que muestre NEUTRO, que el resultado quede así:

```
EstatusReporte    TotalReportes
EN PROCESO           5
RESUELTO             5
```

Alguien que pueda apoyarme, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Solo agregale el que estatus sea diferente a neutro

```
select status as EstatusReporte, count (status) as TotalReportes 
  from Reportes 
  where CveAuxiliar = Numero 
  and where status <> 'NEUTRO'
  group by Status
```

Answer (score 0):

solo filtra NEUTRO en tu consulta...

```
select status as EstatusReporte, count (status) as TotalReportes from Reportes  where CveAuxiliar = Numero and status <> 'NEUTRO' group by Status
```